# 'err' is already declared in the upper scope

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, eslint, chai

My code is giving no errors just i have to meet the eslint as it is giving the error
**'err' is already declared in the upper scope.**
How to fix it in my code here.

```
describe('/GET/:ID', () => {
  it('should Get the task by ID', (done) => {
    const book = new Task({ task: 'The Lord of the Rings' });
    book.save((err, task) => {
      chai.request(server)
        .get(`/task/${task.id}`)
        .send(task)
        .end((err, res) => {
          expect(res).to.have.status(200);
          done();
        });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

ESlint is warning you of [variable shadowing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing), not because it will throw an error or not work, just because sometimes it can be unintentional and thus result in unexpected behaviour e.g. say you were looking to use the `err` from `book.save` inside your `chai` callback?

To fix, just use more explicit naming conventions e.g. `saveErr` / `chaiErr`

Comment: Yup it worked i changed it myself that but is their another way to get through this error on eslint

Comment: @SarveshJhanwar if you don't want to enforce the rule then simply disable the [no-shadow](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-shadow) rule in your ESLint config, or you can disable it purely just for this line of code.

Answer (score 0):

What i was able to figure out that just by changing lower err to error it worked but still is their another way.

```
describe('/GET/:ID', () => {
  it('should Get the task by ID', (done) => {
    const book = new Task({ task: 'The Lord of the Rings' });
    book.save((err, task) => {
      chai.request(server)
        .get(`/task/${task.id}`)
        .send(task)
        .end((error, res) => {
          expect(res).to.have.status(200);
          done();
        });
    });
  });
});
```